# Put HTML markup in PHP if function

Tags: php, drupal

PHP:

```
  if (isset($form['preview_message'])) {

    print drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
    print '</div>';
  }
```

I want like this:

```
 if (isset($form['preview_message'])) {
      <div class="slide-nav">
            <a href="#"><span id="prev"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span id="next"></span></a>

        </div>
    print drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
    print '</div>';
  }
```

I tried but have syntax problems. How can I fix it?

Comment: The way to do it is to use the `?>` tag to drop out of PHP back to HTML, and then `<?php` to switch back to PHP again afterwards

Comment: But you really should consider a cleaner way of working, separating your markup from your PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (isset($form['preview_message'])) {
   ?>
    <div class="slide-nav">
        <a href="#"><span id="prev"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span id="next"></span></a>

    </div>
   <?php
print drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
print '</div>';
}
```

please mark as answer if so, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of the following:

**Close and re-open your PHP tags**

```
if (isset($form['preview_message'])) {
    ?>
    <div class="slide-nav">
        <a href="#"><span id="prev"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span id="next"></span></a>

    </div>
    <?php
    print drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
    print '</div>';
}
```

**Print your HTML with PHP**

```
if (isset($form['preview_message'])) {

    print '<div class="slide-nav">
        <a href="#"><span id="prev"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span id="next"></span></a>

    </div>';

    print drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
    print '</div>';
}
```

**Use the output buffer to store your HTML and print with PHP**

```
if (isset($form['preview_message'])) {

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="slide-nav">
        <a href="#"><span id="prev"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span id="next"></span></a>

    </div>
    <?php
    print ob_get_clean();

    print drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
    print '</div>';
}
```

The first option would suite you best

The option you choose is down to your coding style, i personally prefer to print HTML outside of PHP, as I think it's more readable when making changes, but using the output buffer has its advantages if you are re-using the HTML in multiple places (if you store it as a variable rather than printing)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are printing ending  using print, maybe you should try that to other html output within our script too?

Answer (score 0):

Ore just use "print" again or "echo" :

```
echo '
    <div class="slide-nav">
        <a href="#"><span id="prev"></span></a>
        <a href="#"><span id="next"></span></a>

    </div>';
echo drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
echo  '</div>';
```